# Has Arrow Key Navigation Changed for Skim in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, keybindings, skim

In Mavericks, I was able to scroll through PDFs in Skim by pressing the up/down arrow keys, with the down arrow navigating to later pages in the document, and the up arrow navigating to earlier pages. In Yosemite, it appears that the up and down arrow keys have reversed when viewing a document in either "single page" or "two pages" mode (not continuous); now, the *up* arrow goes to later pages, and the down arrow to earlier pages. Is this a Skim-only change, or is the change more system-wide? If it's system-wide, is there a way to change it back to the Mavericks behavior?

**Edit:** It seems that some people aren't able to reproduce this, so it might be a particular choice of settings that is causing this strange behavior.

Comment: Just tried it myself here on Yosemite and the up/down arrows are behaving as you'd expected.

Comment: In Skim, or another application? For instance the scrollbars in Chrome seem to move the "correct" way with up/down. So it's not everything.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. In Skim.

Comment: Try with "single page" or "two pages" as your PDF display option, *not* continuous. Continuous scrolling seems to work properly.

Comment: Changed it to Single Page. Down button takes me to the next page. Up takes me to the previous page. Same for Two Pages.

Comment: Bizarre! I have no idea why mine has switched then...

Comment: LOL. Changed the settings, no effect. Closed the application, reopened it and now it is doing exactly what you said. Up goes down, down goes up.

Comment: Well at least I know that I'm not going crazy! This might be Skim-only, so I changed the title to be more specific.

Comment: I have the same problem. I use "Space" for next page, so I was very surprised when it started going backwards. In "Single Page Continues" it scroll in the right direction.

Comment: I can confirm the same Effect - since updating to Yosemite Skim keys for next/prev. Page are reversed. I deleted all preference files for skim but had no luck so far identifying the problem.

Comment: Same here. Horrific since I'm doing my first Beamer slides since updating OS.

Comment: By now you've likely noticed it has been fixed. It was a bug that continues in Yosemite and the Skim author was hesitant to include a workaround. It is now in the current version of Skim.

Comment: Broken in El Capitan 10.11.5.  Just terrible behavior. It is necessary to do Shift-space to page down and space to page up. The page up/page down do not work at all .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the author of Skim, there is a bug in Yosemite that swapped the up and down arrow keys. Some versions of Skim had the fix, and the author later decided to remove it. In the newest version of Skim, 1.4.12, the author re-added the workaround. From the changelog:

```
Reinsert workaround for Page Up/Page Down bug Apple refuses to fix
```

Comment: Skim 1.4.12 must have removed support - PgUp/PgDown are again reversed. As a workaround, use `Single-Page Continuous` display.